# Having trouble creating a policy in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have been tasked with an assignment to create what I believe is a bucket policy in AWS. I have uploaded a video to an S3 bucket, and I have to create a policy to limit who can view it based on their IP address. Currently I need to make it so only somebody at my home network can watch it.

I am also supposed to restrict who can watch it based on their username. The bucket is publicly viewable right now and so is the video file.

I have two policies below that I have tried and neither of them are working.

**First Policy:** I have tried using both my private and public IP addresses.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1607205862213",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1607205861134",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::internshipbucket12",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "10.1.10.1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second Policy:** Whenever I try using the arn of my bucket, it gives an error of some kind. When I put in the arn of the video file I am using, it accepts it just fine.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET;",
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why did you replace the policies with their screenshots? I edited your question to fix the formatting earlier.

Comment: I didn’t know you could or we’re going to do that, I figured it would be easier to post pics if things were going to look all messed up

Comment: You say "restrict who can watch it based on their username", but what `username` are you referring to? Is this an AWS login (an IAM User)?

Comment: Try to avoid policies like your first one (an explicit, blanket deny if source IP not 10.1.10.1). If you type the IP address wrong, you will lose access to the bucket. It will deny you access from everywhere except that IP, and because you don't own the mis-typed IP, that means the bucket will be unusable from your home IP, from the AWS console, etc. There's almost never a need to have an explicit, blanket Deny (permissions are implicit deny by default).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. Therefore, there is no need to 'Deny' access, since it is already denied by default. Instead, you should use an 'Allow' policy to permit access.

- Turn off **Block S3 Public Access** (or at least the two parts that refer to Bucket Policies)
- Add a policy that permits access to objects from a given IP address:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::internshipbucket12/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this is granting access to a **public IP address**, and is only permitting `GetObject`, so the user will need to know the exact filename (Key) of the object they want (since it does not grant permission to list the contents of the bucket).